# How does knitr's cache mechanism check whether to run a chunk or not?

Tags: r, caching, knitr

I am writing a document in `knitr` and `Latex` and having trouble with the caching mechanism. Specifically, I have the problem that I write multiple data frames into CSV files to read them in using `pgfplotstable` later on. However, knitr's caching mechanism fails to re-run a chunk if the corresponding CSV file has since been removed or altered in any way. For example, running the following document once, deleting `mwe.dat` and then running it again will produce an error

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<cache=TRUE>>=
df <- data.frame(a=rep(1,5), b=rep(2.5), c=rep(3,5))
write.csv(df, file='mwe.dat')
rm(df)
@

<<cache=FALSE>>=
df <- read.csv(file='mwe.dat')
## Warning: cannot open file ’mwe.dat’: No such file or directory
## Error: cannot open the connection
@
\end{document}
```

So the question is, how does knitr determine that a chunk needs to be re-run? If it's only about actual changes in the source code of the chunk, then I'll have to wrap my (considerable amount of) `write.csv` statements each in their own chunk, despite the fact that most of the time the chunk only sets up the data frame to be written.

Answer (score 1):

The [cache page](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/) in the `knitr` website has explained this issue. In particular, search for `#238` in that page for a similar case.

Comment: From that link: *The issue #238 shows another good use of this option: the cache is associated with the file modification time, i.e. when the data file is modified, the cache will be rebuilt automatically.*